# Use of macros at \DeclareSourcemap

Tags: biblatex, biber

I would like to filter out publications of a single author from a huge bib file using `\DeclareSourcemap`. Thereby, the author name should be configurable with a macro. How could that be done, as the regular way using `\newcommand` seems not to work?

Minimal working example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{foo:2012a,
  title = {My Title One},
  publisher = {My Publisher One},
  year = {2012},
  author = {Schmidt, Achim}
}
@BOOK{foo:2012d,
  title = {My Title Three},
  publisher = {My Publisher Three},
  year = {2012},
  author = {Author, Three}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newcommand{\lastname}{Schmidt}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
        \map{
            \step[fieldsource=author, notmatch=\regexp{\lastname},final]%not working
            %\step[fieldsource=author, notmatch=\regexp{Schmidt},final]%working
            \step[entrynull]
}}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\regexp` is defined in such a way that it (basically) reads its argument verbatim: `\def\regexp#1{\expandafter\zap@space\detokenize{#1} \@empty}`.  `\zap@space <text> \@empty` is meant to expandably remove all spaces from `<text>` (see [`macros2e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/macros2e?lang=en)), which is needed because `\detokenize` doesn't remove spaces while assigning everything else to category 12 ('other').

Comment: I did not really get, what you mean, but i recognized, that there is no need for the  \regexp. If i remove ist, everything works as aspected. (`\step[fieldsource=author, notmatch=\lastname,final]`)

Comment: That is a good solution as long as you don't need any fancy stuff in your regular expressions. If you only match against a name, you are probably fine. But as soon as you need something like `\regexp{\Asistlind\Z}` you are in trouble without the `\regexp`-wrapper.

Comment: Perhaps somebody has an better idea, but this should work using `\regexp{\A}\lastname\regexp{\Z}`

Comment: If it does, you should consider writing up a self-answer so other people can benefit from it. (Or ask jon to write something down if you think that his comment inspired your investigations to a degree large enough.)

Comment: For the record, I'm fine with you answering your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there were no further comments i will try to conclude the solution:

We have to distinguish two cases:

### Simple name filtering

In this case, no regexp is needed and a macro can be used regularly:

```
\step[fieldsource=author, notmatch=\lastname,final]
```

### Advanced regular expression

In this case, the string can be divided into regular string values, where macros can be used and special strings, e.g.:

```
\step[fieldsource=author, notmatch=\regexp{\A}\lastname\regexp{\Z},final]
```

### Usage of special strings within macros

Up to now, I found no solution to include special strings (`\A`) within macros, but I will add here some information if I got it working.